# Bar graph x-axis titles do not work with many bars

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm using MATLAB and I want a bar plot. 
I plotted the bars, and then give titles to the bars.

If I only using 10 bars it works (see pic1).

But often I need more, mostly 32 bars (see pic2).
In this case the titles are not under the bars. I found out that MATLAB don't overlap the titles. The max value is 15 bars.

Does anyone knows how I can get MATLAB to overlap the titles?

Here is my code for plotting the bars:

```
y = absSlopes(1, 1:size(absSlopes,2));
hb = bar(y);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',titles);
rotateXLabels(gca, 45);
ylabel('Anzahl');
```

`absSlopes` is a matrix and I use the complete first line.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try `XTick` in addition to `XTickLabel`. At least for regular plots you can enforce specific spacings through this setting.

You can do this by an additional setup-command:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',titles);
set(gca,'XTick',absSlopes(1,:));
```

Of course, you can set both properties in the same line, but I like to keep it simple in case you want to deactiviate/comment one or the other setting later on.

Comment: Thank you very much, i reached the goal ;)
I only edited your solution to "set(gca,'XTick',1:size(absSlopes,2));"

Really really thank you :-)

Comment: @pyStarter Does `1:size(absSlopes,2)` need to be in the second `set` command as suggested by SolarTurtle? Apparently his edit was rejected and the OP resorted to putting the "solution" in his question.  :)

Comment: I do not think so as it does not matter. Here is why: `absSlopes(1,:)` will grab all columns of the first line of *absSlopes*. On the other hand, `1:size(absSlopes,2)` will contain all column-indices of *absSlopes* from 1 to end and thus `absSlopes(1, 1:size(absSlopes,2))` will return the same as my (shorter) command.